# Is there any efficient structure to reference cached buffer conversions in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[As this GitHub thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19736) discusses, there's a reason `Map`'s `.has` method doesn't work with buffers, as two identical buffers are effectively two distinct, different objects.

So when I tried to store buffer string conversions to a map to cache results to test for a potential optimization opportunity by caching the results of `Buffer.toString('utf8')` to a map, I was disappointed. Of course I can convert the buffer to some other form to key it to the map, but I'd then also have to convert it each time I test the cache, sort of defeating the purpose.

```
const readStr = (buffer) => {
  if (strMap.has(buffer)) {
    return strMap.get(buffer)
  } else {
    result = buffer.toString("utf8");
    strMap.set(buffer, result)
    return result
  }
}
```

So I figured I should just ask. Is there a viable way of caching buffer `.toString()` results? Is this optimization fundamentally possible in JavaScript?

Edit: The number of possible unique strings in my data is known and small (< 10000) and all strings in my use-case have a length of 5.

Comment: I don't think it's worth the effort. JavaScript engines are optimized for handling `string` values efficiently, even short-lived strings. What profiling or benchmarking have you done that suggests you should be memoizing this anyway? (Source: I used to work on Chakra at Microsoft) (Not to mention the sheer memory cost of memoizing every possible string in any of your buffers (aka String Interning) - ouch!)

Comment: What if instead of using the whole Buffer.toString as a cache (essentially), you use some hash as key?

Comment: @raina77ow The computational cost of computing the hash of a buffer is going to be on the same order-of-magnitude as invoking `toString`, and potentially actually *worse* given that `toString` is generally implemented in native code inside the engine while hashing a buffer would have to be done using other JS.

Comment: @Dai Agreed. Been thinking about slightly different cases, dealing with external resources instead of Buffers.

Comment: @Dai I'll show you why I'm at least trying it. See lines 119 - 126. https://gist.github.com/jt0dd/b9c57298dab7af97bc3fd3d51e06e3f0. In a scenario where I'd like to achieve the absolute maximum read speed for `readBuffer`, the string conversion is the slowest. I'm just interested in testing every possible optimization

Comment: @J.Todd If you really wanted to maximize the speed of your application you wouldn't be writing in JavaScript (*despite* the decent perf of Google's V8 and Node.JS). Consider that by choosing NodeJS you're choosing a tool designed for performance-of-productivity, not performance-of-code - so you're swimming upstream and going against the flow of the ecosystem. I advise you to not proceed any further **unless profiling and benchmarks show otherwise**.

Comment: @J.Todd The benchmark you posted in your GitHub gist is a **synthetic benchmark**, it is not representative of how your application code will perform under actual production loads. In SE there's a concept of "[speedup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup)" - and I'm very sure that the _speedup_ from microoptimizing your `readStr` is absolutely not worth it at all - and in fact, the probable massive amount of memory you'll need to store your hashset will erase any gains in the long-run. **There's a reason this functionality is not a part of JavaScript as-is**.

Comment: @Dai I should have included in my question that the number of different strings that can exist in my data is known and small.

Comment: @J.Todd If the input domain is very small then you probably don't need an open-ended buffer - have you considered using a state-machine/automata to handle input (and emit an enum) instead?

Comment: @Dai I realize speedup happens on the processor but since in this code, like I said I'm already performing `toString()` on the same strings hundreds of thousands of times by the time I get those benchmarks I commented in, so the processor has already had time to exhibit speedup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222819/discussion-between-j-todd-and-dai).

Comment: @Dai Figured it out actually. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. This cache solution yields a 25% improvement:

```
const readStr = (buffer) => {
    key = "" + buffer[0] + buffer[1] + buffer[2] + buffer[3] + buffer[4]
    if (strMap.has(key)) {
        return strMap.get(key)
    } else {
        result = buffer.toString("utf8");
        strMap.set(key, result)
        return result
    }
}
```

Again, this is only viable in a scenario when you know the number of unique strings you'll encounter is fairly small. Additionally, since my strings all have a length of 5, this is more efficient than it would be for a larger string (the `toString()` conversion takes longer on larger strings as well, so this isn't to say the optimization can't work there too.

For a wider range of unique strings (more than you'd like to hold in buffer) you can update it to slice the cache and only store, say, the 10,000 most recent items to potentially get some lesser optimization (since you won't have a 100% cache and maintaining the array size isn't free.

All in all, this is a fairly specific use-case for optimization, but hey, someone might see it and find it useful.

Comment: I think using a template string might be faster than 6 concatenations.

Comment: @AKX that's an excellent idea, I had no idea that feature existed in JS after working with the language for 8 years now. Testing

Comment: @AKX Do you mean like: `key = String.fromCodePoint(buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4])` or `key = String.raw({
    raw: [buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4]]
  })` ?

Comment: I meant `key = \`${buffer[0]}${buffer[1]}${buffer[2]}${buffer[3]}${buffer[4]}\`;`

Comment: @AKX roughly identical

Comment: That would fail with 2 equal buffers but the first 2 bytes. For example, if one buffer has the first two bytes being `2, 13` and the second buffer has the first two bytes as `21, 3`, it will render the same string concatenation. You must differenciate them somehow. The `fromCodePoint/raw` methods are not bugged like this one as each one is a different character.